# Access C++ objects from C callback

Tags: c++, c, callback, mqtt, mbed

I'm writing a C++ application for an embedded platform (ARM CORTEX4) using the [mbed framework](http://mbed.org). [I'm using the new Paho Embedded C++/C client](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/embedded/) library. [Here is the library's code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.embedded-c.git/tree/MQTTClient/src/MQTTClient.h). Everything works as expected, except of the subscribe callbacks.

This is the definition of the subscribe method:

```
 /** MQTT Subscribe - send an MQTT subscribe packet and wait for the suback
 *  @param topicFilter - a topic pattern which can include wildcards
 *  @param qos - the MQTT QoS to subscribe at
 *  @param mh - the callback function to be invoked when a message is received for this subscription
 *  @return success code -
 */
int subscribe(const char* topicFilter, enum QoS qos, messageHandler mh);
```

with messageHandler defined as:

```
typedef void (*messageHandler)(MessageData&);
```

and MessageData as:

```
struct MessageData
{
    MessageData(MQTTString &aTopicName, struct Message &aMessage)  : message(aMessage), topicName(aTopicName)
    { }

    struct Message &message;
    MQTTString &topicName;
};
```

and Message as:

```
struct Message
{
    enum QoS qos;
    bool retained;
    bool dup;
    unsigned short id;
    void *payload;
    size_t payloadlen;
};
```

Since my software is written in C++, I can't find a way to pass a context variable into the callback. So currently don't see a way to access my objects from within the callback.

I've seen in the API of a different MQTT client ([Paho MQTT C Client for Unix / Mac / Windows](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/_m_q_t_t_client_8h.html#aad27d07782991a4937ebf2f39a021f83)) that it accepts for example a void* to pass the context into the callback.

Am I missing something or what is the best strategy to access objects outside of the callback?

The only thing I could think of, is some static variables in a class. Which again seems to be a bit "ugly" to me.

Any hints are very much appreciated!

Comment: First of all, I do not see C code in your question. Second, callback can receive only those parameteres that are passed. You can try some flavor of thread local variable (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local) if it will work for your task and is availaibe on your system.

Comment: There are ways to mix C and C++ code - this article illustrates few techniques https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp . In your case the callback prototype does not have the context parameter so you may have to change it.